# Create IFTTT recipe to post a Facebook status at a specific date/time

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that

I want to create a recipe in IFTTT like:

Update Facebook status on a date or time. But I cannot find any way, instead there is STATUS trigger for publishing the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an IFTTT recipe, you need a trigger and action.

In your case, your *Action* is to post a Facebook status. Fortunately, the [Facebook channel](https://ifttt.com/facebook) has a Post Status action available.

Your *Trigger* is a specific date/time. You want to use the [Date & Time channel](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time) for your trigger.

[Create a new recipe](https://ifttt.com/myrecipes/personal/new) and...

...for **This** select the **Date & Time** channel and choose the appropriate trigger. These triggers are designed to be recurring triggers, but one presumes that you'll delete the recipe once the status is posted. (I'd choose the "Every year on" trigger.)

...for **That** select the **Facebook** channel and choose the appropriate action, which as we've established is "Create a status message". Add the text of the status message you want.

That's all you need.

If you prefer, you can take [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/139889), which is currently for posting a "Happy New Year" status, and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to schedule a post on a Facebook Page rather than a personal account, it is possible to schedule posts with Facebook's own built in functionality. Just click the little clock icon below the status entry box, and that will show you the post scheduling interface.